# Is there a way to programatically change the value of a property in Flutter TextTheme?

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I'd like to change the style for the `textTheme` variable. I want to edit dynamically the `headline2` property, as I read the value from a JSON, and don't want to go with conditionals all the way to cover all the cases.

JSON snippet:

```
{
  "headline2": {
    "color": "0x000000",
    "fontFamily": "opr"
  }
}
```

Code snippet:

```
var textTheme = TextTheme(
  headline2: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.white,
    fontFamily: "ark"
  )
);
```

Is there a way to do this?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update every single widget of your application dynamically when your variable `textTheme` is modified, you will probably need a `ChangeNotifierProvider`.

I suppose that `TextTheme` will be added to `ThemeData` so you will need your `ChangeNotifierProvider` to be above `MaterialApp` at the very beginning of your code.

Then, your `ChangeNotifier` should probably looks like this:

```
class ThemeProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
   bool darkTheme;

   ThemeProvider() {
      darkTheme = true;
   }

   changeTheme()
   {
      darkTheme = !darkTheme;
      notifyListeners();
   }
}
```

And your textTheme will be modified like that:

```
final ThemeProvider _themeProvider =
    Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);

    var textTheme = _themeProvider.darkTheme ? TextTheme(
      headline2: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontFamily: "ark"
      ) : TextTheme(
      headline2: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
        fontFamily: "ark"
      )
    );
```

Each time `changeTheme()` function will be called, textTheme and, consequently, your app will be updated entirely.

If you are not familiar with `ChangeNotifierProvider`: [Simple App State Management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple)